# What is a bow shelf?

Tags: gear, archery, recurve-bow, long-bows

I'm new to archery and bought a book. However, the author is often using the term "bow shelf" and I can't really imagine what this might be.

So, what is a "bow shelf"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Shelf

The answer is really simple. It's the little "cut out" just above the grip. This edge where you can "lay down" your arrow while you shoot. A picture might help:

[image: Bow shelf]

[image: Shelf illustration]

*Note: An "arrow rest" is something different!*

### Design patterns

Some notes on the different designs which may occur:

> There are 3 basic types of shelf designs; flat, radiused and ridged.
>   The diagrams below picture these 3 variations.
>
> [image: Design patterns]
>
> The radiused shelf is the most common on both longbows and recurves.
>   As illustrated in the picture, the radius reduces the amount of
>   arrow-to-bow contact.
>
> The flat shelf is also relatively common, especially on some older
>   styled recurves. When a bow has this style of shelf it is necessary to
>   use an elevated rest to get the fletching clearance necessary for good
>   arrow flight. One trick that has been used in this situation is to
>   place a thin narrow strip of leather under a rug rest and continue it
>   up the sightwindow under the strike plate. This will allow more
>   clearance and therefore help with flight.
>
> The ridged shape, I believe, is the design that offers the best
>   clearance, since the arrow-to-bow contact is at its absolute minimum.

From [Stickbow](http://www.stickbow.com/FEATURES/BOWBUILDING/shelf.CFM)